# How to migrate a password hash?

Tags: security, passwords, md5, bcrypt

If I have passwords stored as a salted MD5 hash, but want to move them to use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), what's the best way to perform that transition? (given that I can't get the passwords back)

Should I bcrypt the md5 hash? Are there cryptographic implications to doing that that I don't want?

Comment: What would you gain from hashing the existing MD5 hashes? Your application will still need to know which sort of hash function each user's password was hashed with and possibly try both when authenticating. So I don't see the benefit of rehashing.

Comment: The advantage to hashing the md5 hash with bcrypt is that in can be unilaterally applied to the db.  No need to wait for the user to re-input the clear text pw.

Comment: found this blog post which asserts it's ok, but no idea what that's based on http://thepileof.blogspot.ca/2012/06/how-to-migrate-database-of-stored.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, sites simply make users change their passwords.  If you add a hash_version field to your users table, you can keep track of the current hash type.  When someone with MD5 logs in, make them change their passwords.

After a certain amount of time, you can optionally expire all the remaining MD5 passwords (forcing users to reset to log in).